# VBA Debug, How to step through multiple loops at once

Tags: excel, vba

I have a loop that loops through 10k rows. I am having trouble with one record in the middle and I want to see what the code is doing around the 5k row mark.
This is not practical to do f5 on each next.

How can I run up to a specified loop or row number?

Comment: Why is this getting down/close voted? I think this is a valid question with enough details to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put something like `If i = 5000 Then Stop` in your loop. The code will then stop at `i = 5000` in debug mode with `Stop` highlighted. You can then proceed step by step using F9.

#### For loop

```
For i = 1 to 10000 '<-- this is YOUR loop!
    If i = 5000 Then Stop

    'your other code here
Next i
```

---

#### Do loop

If it is a `Do` loop put in a counter `i`

```
Dim i As Long
Do While Criteria = True
    i = i + 1
    If i = 5000 Then Stop

    'your other code here
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks, so for your For Loop answer, this should wrap around my existing loop?

Comment: just put `If i = 5000 Then Stop` as first line into your existing `for` loop. The rest was just to illustrate where to put it.

Comment: This may seem wishful, but is there a way to skip to loop 5000? Its taking me awhile to get to that halfway mark lol.

Comment: well then let your loop start at 5000 like `For i = 5000 To 10000` just adjust to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Learn to use `Debug.Assert` this will automatically pause your code when it evaluates to `False`. For example:

```
Sub Demo_Debug_Assert()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 100
        Debug.Assert i < 50
    Next i
End Sub
```

Will break on every value of `i` greater than 49. This condition can obviously be changed for your criteria so:

```
Debug.Assert i <> 5000
```

If you want it to break just on `5000` or

```
Debug.Assert i < 5000
```

for the code to break on every value after `4999`

To further this, instead of worrying about removing these lines before you use the code you can create a global constant (here named `DebugMode`) which is a `Boolean` so that this isn't triggered

```
Const DebugMode = True
Sub Demo_Debug_Assert()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 100
        If DebugMode Then Debug.Assert i < 50
    Next i
End Sub
```

Changing the global constant to  `Const DebugMode = False` will run your code to the end without pausing

Comment: You could also use a conditional compiling `#If DEBUGMODE Then` and set a *Conditional Compilation Argument* at project level to switch into debug mode. See [Setting Up a Debug Environment for VBA](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/11/21/setting-up-a-debug-environment-for-vba/). So that's not a simple `If` switch that is run every time the code runs but a switch that compiles either the one or the other code based on the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Add an increment variable in your loop and then, a condition like this :

```
i = i + 1
if i = 5000 then
   i = 5000                        <---- Do F9 here
end if
```

Do F9 on the "i = 5000" line to add a breakpoint for debugging.

This will stop the running at 5000 iteration

Comment: Thanks, so where in my loop should i put this code? Before the `next` ?

Comment: @excelguy before the `next` or just after the `for`